# PyQt5 How to make updating progress bar when line from text is reading?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, progress-bar

I'm a beginner in Python and PyQt. I want to do simple UI - click button opens file dialog, next choose text file and it's adding to list line by line. And this part works fine. When file has about 500k lines adding takes some time, so decided to make a progress bar. I was searching how to do this and here is my code:

```
SIZE = 0
VALUE = 0

class External(QThread):
        countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
        def run(self):
                while VALUE <= SIZE:
                counter = (VALUE*100/SIZE)
                time.sleep(1)
                self.countChanged.emit(int(counter))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
                \... some UI setup ...\
                self.listView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
                self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)
                self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        
        def openFile(self):
                global SIZE
                global VALUE
                openfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.pushButton, "Open File", "", "TXT (*.txt)")
                SIZE = os.stat(openfile[0]).st_size
                if not openfile[0] == "":
                        with open(openfile[0], 'r') as f:
                                file_text = f.readlines()
                                self.calc = External()
                                self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
                                self.calc.start()
                        for line in file_text:
                                self.listView.addItem(line)
                                VALUE = VALUE + sys.getsizeof(line)

        def onCountChanged(self, counter):
                self.progressBar.setValue(counter)
```

Text is added to list properly each time. The progress bar sometimes doesn't load at all, sometimes loads up to several percent (e.g. 23%), but doesn't show real-time progress, it looks as the progress value was added after loading the entire list.

**1)** Not sure if I can use getsizeof() to check how much data has already been processed - What should I use instead?

**2)** Why my progress bar doesn't work properly? What the code should look like?

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it does not show "real-time progress" because you're sleeping for a whole second, which is not very "real-timey".

Then, you're using `sys.getsizeof`, which is the size of the *object*, not the size of the line, so you must use `len(line)`.

The reason for the inaccurate result of the progress bar reside both in the amount of `sleep` *and* the wrong size computation: if the size was computed correctly it would never exit the while loop, but since you're actually getting a VALUE that will become much higher than SIZE *and* you're checking it only each 1 second, the loop exits too "early".

Finally, maybe a better approach would be to let the thread take care of the loading (and then populate the list using a signal that emits the text); this will make it more accurate and *actually* real time.

```
class Loader(QtCore.QThread):
    lineLoaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        super().__init__()
        self.filePath = filePath

    def run(self):
        with open(self.filePath, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                self.lineLoaded.emit(line)
                sleep(.001)

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load file')
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)

    def loadFile(self):
        openfile, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "TXT (*.txt)")
        if not openfile:
            return
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(QtCore.QFileInfo(openfile).size())
        self.loader = Loader(openfile)
        self.loader.lineLoaded.connect(self.loading)
        self.loader.start()

    def loading(self, line):
        self.listView.addItem(line)
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.progressBar.value() + len(line))
```

<sub>An unrelated suggestion: it seems like you're trying to mimic the output of a `pyuic` command or you've just edited that file. This is something that should *never* be done (for various reasons, including the fact that if you need to update your UI, you end up with a very difficult process of reintegrating the existing code with the UI modifications). I suggest you to read more about correctly [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Also, avoid using globals like this, is considered bad practice and can easily lead to problems and bugs.</sub>